# Error "Unable to find a source package for r-base" on Debian Testing

Tags: r, debian

Before installing R from source, I normally do "sudo apt-get build-dep r-base" which always worked under Ubuntu. Now I have a Debian (Testing) machine with LXDE and when executing the above, I obtain "E: Unable to find a source package for r-base". What might be the cause of this error?

**Update**

I forgot to add `deb http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3` and `deb-src http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. After `sudo apt-get update`, I obtained:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://stat.ethz.ch jessie-cran3/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 06F90DE5381BA480
```

As the section cran.r-project.org -> Download R for Linux -> debian -> SECURE APT says, a key needs to be added. As this failed, I did it slightly differently via `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key <NUMBER>` where `<NUMBER>` is the number given above, so 06F90DE5381BA480

Comment: Did you add the repository to your apt sources file?

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks for helping. That's the strange part, I did not have to do this on Ubuntu and /etc/apt/sources.list did not show any R related entry there. What would I have to put in there?

Comment: *argh*, sure, on CRAN... I'll try that...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you had to do this on Ubuntu too, but it might have been quite awhile ago, so maybe you forgot you did? For those following along, here are the [instructions for Debian CRAN binaries](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/).

Comment: Hi Joshua, thanks again for helping, it now worked. I'm still puzzled by my old Ubuntu setting. I don't have any R related setting in /etc/apt/sources.list. The only server-related setting I have is in ~/.Rprofile: `options(repos=c(CRAN="http://cran.ch.r-project.org"))`. Maybe that's where the server came from. Cheers, M.

Comment: Maybe you only need to add something to your apt sources to get packages? I'm not certain. Regardless, I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: ... just realized, I still get `E: Unable to find a source package for r-base` *sigh* (even after reboot... and despite my `/etc/apt/sources.list` now containing `deb http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/`)

Comment: I got it... miss the `deb-src` entry...

Comment: What is "Debian Testing"? A special edition of Debian? Or do you mean "Debian testing"?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 381BA480

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install r-base
```